# How to to capture & apply changes from specific tables on a postgresql database to a master postgresql database

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, replication

I need  to capture & apply changes from specific tables on a postgresql database to a master postgresql database, I only need the insert/update/delete events over those specific tables, I found an example using [Audit_trigger_91plus](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)!  for capture the changes over my tables, but i don't know if this is a good idea, cause after the capture I need to convert this logs into sql statements, escape the values, and check the concurrency. My question is if there are another simplest way to achieve that.  PHP it's used for the application over those two databases and for the future replication services and management.

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you just use BDR: https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JimNasby,  I'll check it out later

Comment: Bad news @JimNasby the BDR documentation say: "As of the time of writing, the upcoming PostgreSQL 9.5 release is not yet supported. Neither is Microsoft Windows. Support for both will be added in later releases; please check the BDR website for the latest information." and "Windows is not supported at this time. There is no major technical barrier to doing so but it has not been a time allocation priority"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem, The solution was to implement a java app who read the changes stored in the audit table (thanks to the [Audit_trigger_91plus](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)),  transform this hstore data into valids sql statements using sql injection, and then apply one by one in master database. Thank you all and if you find another better approach please add your comments.